# AngularCLI Production Build Breaks Dictionary Injection

Tags: angular, angular-cli

We have an Angular application which we followed the advice in this turorial:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-language-translation-in-angular-2-part-1

In order to have a simple framework for replacing values based on which deployment it is.  This all works fine but when we do an angular cli --prod build the translations object is empty.

The basic setup is as per the attached tutorial but basically we have a const as follows:

```
export const COLL1_TRANSLATIONS = {
"Key1": "Value1",
"Key2": "Value2",
"Key3": "Value3",
};

// translation token
export const TRANSLATIONS = new InjectionToken('translations');

// all translations
const dictionary = {};
dictionary["COLL1_NAME"] = COLL1_TRANSLATIONS;

// providers
export const TRANSLATION_PROVIDERS = [
    { provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: dictionary },
];

@Injectable()
export class TranslateService {
  public get currentLang() {
    return this._currentLang || this._defaultLang;
  }

  // inject our translations
  constructor( @Inject(TRANSLATIONS) private _translations: any) {
    console.log(_translations);
  }
}
```

When we run the build without --prod everything works fine and the console.log has the populated dictionary, when we run with --prod on the cli build the dictionary is empty.

This is several code snippets from several files to give the basic idea but is almost identical to the tutorial link above, as mentioned works absolutely as expected when we don't do a --prod build so the question is why is --prod breaking the injection of the dictionary?

UPDATE:
If I add --aot=false to the prod build then everything works fine again, is there a way to make this work with aot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because your code is not AOT compatible, when you exectue ng buil --prod, aot is true by default, try to change your code to

```
 export function tokenInjectionFunction () { 
      return new InjectionToken('translations'); 
 };
```

instead of

```
export const TRANSLATIONS = new InjectionToken('translations');
```

and try to change your translation providers from this:

```
export const TRANSLATION_PROVIDERS = [
  { provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: dictionary },
];
```

To:

```
let dictionary = {};
dictionary["COLL1_NAME"] = COLL1_TRANSLATIONS;
export function getTransProviders() {
  return dictionary;
}

export const TRANSLATION_PROVIDERS = [
 { provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: getTransProviders},
];
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, I have tried the change you suggested but the dictionary is still empty when injected the TranslateService constructor when I do a --prod build, are there any other changes required to make this compatible with AOT?

Comment: i updated the answer i wish that it will work now and change const dictionary to let dictionary

Comment: Thanks for you help, that did the trick, although in the constructor of TranslateService I had to call: constructor(
    @Inject(translationsTokenInjectionFunction) private _translations) {
    this._translations = this._translations();
  } but that got it working, thanks for your help.